# System of equations program error

Tags: c#

I made a systems of equations program and I am not getting the correct answer. Im using 4x + y = 8 and 5x + 2y = 13 for the test problem. The correct answer should be x = 1, y =4, but I'm getting x = .75 and y = 5. I don't know what the error is, but I would appreciate some help fixing it. Thanks

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter row1 col1");
        string strX1 = Console.ReadLine();
        double dblX1 = Convert.ToDouble(strX1);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter row1 col2");
        string strY1 = Console.ReadLine();
        double dblY1 = Convert.ToDouble(strY1);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter row1 col3");
        string strZ1 = Console.ReadLine();
        double dblZ1 = Convert.ToDouble(strZ1);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter row2 col1");
        string strX2 = Console.ReadLine();
        double dblX2 = Convert.ToDouble(strX1);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter row2 col2");
        string strY2 = Console.ReadLine();
        double dblY2 = Convert.ToDouble(strY2);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter row2 col3");
        string strZ2 = Console.ReadLine();
        double dblZ2 = Convert.ToDouble(strZ2);

        double dblX1New = dblX2 * dblX1;
        double dblY1New = dblX2 * dblY1;
        double dblZ1New = dblX2 * dblZ1;
        double dblX2New = (dblX1 * -1) * dblX2;
        double dblY2New = (dblX1 * -1) * dblY2;
        double dblZ2New = (dblX1 * -1) * dblZ2;

        double dblX = dblX1New + dblX2New;
        double dblY = dblY1New + dblY2New;
        double dblZ = dblZ1New + dblZ2New;

        double dblYFinal = dblZ / dblY;
        double dblXFinal = (dblZ1 - dblYFinal * dblY1) / dblX1;

        Console.WriteLine("X: " + dblXFinal + " Y: " + dblYFinal);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter row2 col1");
string strX2 = Console.ReadLine();
double dblX2 = Convert.ToDouble(strX1); <--- Error
```

You're converting `strX1` instead of `strX2`. As a result, it thinks the two X values are the same.

Comment: Side note: tools can help here. I'm using VS 2013 and Resharper, and when I copy/pasted your code, the variable `strX2` was grayed out, indicating it was not being used.

Comment: I knew it was something really simple I just kept looking over and couldn't find, but thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped you, feel free to upvote it; if it solved your problem, you can click the check mark.